# Jboss 4.2 Class Loading

Tags: java, jboss, classloader, jboss-4.2.x

I have a jar in `server/default/lib` which contains `Foo.class`,`Bar.class`

and the same class is there in my `application/WEB-INF/classes` which is deployed in `server/default/deploy`.

and `Example.class` is using the `Foo.class` instance and `Bar.class` instance

Now the situation is that `Example.class` shoud use the `Foo.class` in my application and `Bar.class` in `default/lib` jar file.

i.e. my application should use the classes in the application clases folder if not found in classes folder then it should use the class in `default/lib` jar files.

To do i have defined `jboss-web.xml` file

```
<jboss-web>
   <class-loading java2ClassLoadingCompliance="true">
   <loader-repository>
         com.example:eagle=web-360.jar
         <loader-repository-config>java2ParentDelegation=true</loader-repository-config>
      </loader-repository> 
   </class-loading>
</jboss-web>
```

`web-360.jar` is the jar which will be `default/lib`.
`com.eagle:eagle` has no significance..

Comment: Please rephrase your text to include an actual question.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [JBossClassLoadingUseCases](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossClassLoadingUseCases). Your situation seems to be Use Case 4 (i.e. the class will be loaded from `default/lib` in preference to `WEB-INF/classes`.

What you seem to want is Use Case 3 (i.e. `WEB-INF/classes` preferred to `default/lib`), in which case you should omit the `java2ParentDelegation=true` config option from `jboss-web.xml` (or set it to `false`, which is the default).